# Is there any way to play the original main Destiny storyline without Xbox Live Gold?

Tags: destiny, xbox-network

I just ported over from PS4, and this is the ***only*** game I could afford at the time. I want to know if there's a way to play the **original** storyline, that is, the storyline prior to the release of Rise of Iron and the Taken King.

I play Destiny and I'm familiar to the game and such. I'm not even mad, because I have to make a new character. I just don't feel like paying 9.99 a month (or other payment options) for one game. I have played maybe 4 missions, but it seems like I can't play Strikes without Xbox Live Gold. I can't play in Offline mode, because if I am unable to connect to the Destiny servers, I can't access the game.

Are there any specific workarounds or anything so I don't have to pay a fee to play a single game on a single console that I *barely* use?

Answer (score 2):

[Destiny is an online-only game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny_(video_game)) (see the very first sentence of the Wikipedia article).  You will need an internet connection to your Xbox at the minimum because you need to be connected to the Bungie servers.  You can do this through an [Xbox Live Silver](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-xbox-live-silver-3563184) membership.  The big difference between Xbox Live Silver and Gold is that with Silver, you cannot play multiplayer (and it is free).

Answer (score -1):

Well the answer turns out to be no you can't. Some of the story missions actually require you to be a part of a fire-team of other players, so no xbox live gold, no completing the story missions either.

Just found this out now as i've got to level 20.